# Replacing an one of the objects in an array of objects in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have below array and object and I am trying to replace the entire object of the array where id matches.

```
this.integrationActionsArray = [{id: 1, key: 'some key', value: 'some value'}]
myObject = {id: 1, key: 'another key', value: 'another value'}
```

so far I have made below attempts to change the one of the entire objects of an array of objects

```
 this.integrationActionsArray
                    .find(data => {
                        if (data.id == myId) {
                            data = myObject
                        }
                    })
console.log(this.integrationActionsArray)
```

Expectation of the above log is something like below

```
[{id: 1, key: 'another key', value: 'another value'}]
```

but it is still like

```
[{id: 1, key: 'some key', value: 'some value'}]
```

I have tried using forEach, filter, map and every other iterator but still no luck.

Comment: Can you clarify which final array structure/values you require?

Comment: I am expecting [{id: 1, key: 'another key', value: 'another value'}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `data = myObject`, what you are expecting does not happen.

`data` is just a local variable that points to the `integrationActionsArray` array element in the `find` callback method. Once you run the above statement, you are not changing anything in the array, instead just reassigning `data`.

A simple representation of what is happening above.

```js
let data = { a : 1 , b : 2 };

let data1 = data;

data1={x : 1};
//You can not expect data to change
console.log(data);
```

To fix this grab the index, and then replace the element in the array.

```js
const integrationActionsArray = [{id: 1, key: 'some key', value: 'some value'}];

const myObject = {id: 1, key: 'another key', value: 'another value'};
const myId = 1;
integrationActionsArray
                    .forEach((data,index) => {
                        if (data.id == myId) {
                            integrationActionsArray[index] = myObject
                        }
                    })
console.log(integrationActionsArray)
```

**Note:** The above code will work with [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) but `find` returns a specific element. And a simple [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) is ideal for the above case.